# Encrypted PDF won't write to disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I have some code that is encrypting a pdf, and for some reason as soon as I encrypt the pdf, the writing hangs.  If I comment out `pdf_writer.encrypt(password)` there is no problem and things are written properly.  I've tried running the script with the highest privileges and modifying the folder options, but maybe I'm missing something simple.

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as pdf_file:
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    for page_number in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page_number))

    pdf_writer.encrypt(password)
    filename_encrypted = filename.parents[0] / f "{filename.stem}_encrypted.pdf"

    with open(filename_encrypted, 'wb') as pdf_file_encrypted:
        pdf_writer.write(pdf_file_encrypted)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why things weren't working with PyPDF2, so I just tried another module called pikepdf and things worked just fine.  This actually seems like a much better module than PyPDF2 anyway.

```
import pikepdf


filename = pathlib.Path(r"path\to\pdf\test.pdf")
password = 'password'

with Pdf.open(filename) as pdf:
    filename_encrypted = filename.parents[0] / f"{filename.stem}_encrypted.pdf"
    pdf.save(filename_encrypted, encryption=Encryption(user=password, owner=password))
```